# Двоичная куча на основе связного списка

Tags: java, алгоритм, дерево, linked-list

Здравствуйте!

Никогда не сталкивался с двоичной кучей, но получил на дз реализовать с помощью массива и связного списка на джава

С массивом проблем не возникло, так как там к каждому участку памяти можно достучаться

А вот с связным списком у меня нету идей, каким образом добавлять элемент в кучу?

Как "проходить" по списку до того самого элемента, в который нужно добавить новый элемент кучи?

Какая структура лучше подойдет к куче:

-Куча: указатель на голову сбалансированного дерева, которое представленно отдельным классом и имеет левого сына, правого сына, информацию, которая хранится в данном корне.

-Куча: информация в корне, левый сын, правый сын

И еще вопрос, каким образом строить сбалансированное дерево? Какой алгоритм его построения, как через линейный список проверять "сбалансированность"?

Возможно, где-то есть пример, где уже построили на джаве с помощью связного списка дерево, но я ничего по этой теме не нашел. Буду благодарен, если вдруг укажете мне на источник.

Да, я понимаю, я на программиста учусь и должен сам это все воспроизводить, это основы, но я впервые с этим имею дело и ниразу не видел сбалансированной кучи на основе связного списка, даже в теории нам об этом не говорили, просто кинули дз, дедлайн и дали ссылку на википедию, прошу отнестись с пониманием.

Comment: то есть вам надо реализовать дерево используя связанный список?

Comment: Да, абсолютно верно, но дерево - сбалансированное(или же это называют кучей)